# Menu using switches doesn't accept my input, in power shell?

Tags: c#, powershell, menu, switch-statement

I have this project for school, where I'm supposed to create a menu for several reasons, to which I'm using switches for processing the options that should take me to a new switch which should then be a new sub menu. For some reason however it instead simply takes me down my switch, no matter the choice I make it simply jumps to the next switch. My code is written below. The program I'm using is Power shell.

```
$Title = "Main Management"
$Message = "Welcome to the Management Menu"

$ChoiceOU = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Create OU", `
    "Add OU creation"

$ChoiceGroup = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Group", `
     "Group"
    $ChoiceAddGroup = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Create Group", `
        "Add Group"
    $ChoiceAddGroupCSV = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Create Group from CSV", `
        "Add Group from CSV"
$TitleGroup = "Group Management"
$MessageGroup = "Choose your group creation"


$ChoiceUser = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&User", `
     "User"
    $ChoiceAddUser = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Create User", `
        "Add User"
    $ChoiceAddUserCSV = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Create User from CSV", `
        "Add User from CSV"
$TitleUser = "User Creation"
$MessageUser = "Creation form"

$UserList = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Export Userlist", `
    "Export Lists"

$DeleteUser = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Delete User", `
    "Delete User"

$EditUser = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Edit User", `
    "Edit User"

$MainOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceOU, $ChoiceGroup, $ChoiceUser, $UserList, $DeleteUser, $EditUser)
    $MainMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $Message, $MainOptions, 0)

$SubGroupOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddGroup, $ChoiceAddGroupCSV)
    $SubGroupMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleGroup, $MessageGroup, $SubGroupOptions, 0)

$SubUserOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddUser, $ChoiceAddUserCSV)
    $SubUserMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleUser, $MessageUser, $SubUserOptions, 0)

$CreateGroupForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 



switch ($MainMenu)
    {
        0 {"You selected OU"}
        1 {$SubGroupMenu}
        2 {$SubUserMenu}
        3 {"You selected User List"}
        4 {"You selected Delete User"}
        5 {"You selected Edit User"}
    }

 switch ($SubGroupMenu)
    {           
            0 {$CreateGroupForm.showdialog()}
            1 {"CSV Import"} 
    }
 switch ($SubUserMenu)
    {
            0 {"User Creation"}
            1 {"Choose CSV"}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be two reasons why your code simply runs through each switch rather than being directed by the choices that the user makes.

The first issue is that you do not have any logic determining when the prompts are shown. The lines:

```
$MainOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceOU, $ChoiceGroup, $ChoiceUser, $UserList, $DeleteUser, $EditUser)
        $MainMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $Message, $MainOptions, 0)

    $SubGroupOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddGroup, $ChoiceAddGroupCSV)
        $SubGroupMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleGroup, $MessageGroup, $SubGroupOptions, 0)

    $SubUserOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddUser, $ChoiceAddUserCSV)
        $SubUserMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleUser, $MessageUser, $SubUserOptions, 0)
```

as written will execute sequentially regardless of the value supplied at the previous prompt. You can do something like this:

```
$MainOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceOU, $ChoiceGroup, $ChoiceUser, $UserList, $DeleteUser, $EditUser)
    $MainMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $Message, $MainOptions, 0)

if($MainMenu -eq 1){
$SubGroupOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddGroup, $ChoiceAddGroupCSV)
    $SubGroupMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleGroup, $MessageGroup, $SubGroupOptions, 0)
}

if($MainMenu -eq 2){
$SubUserOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddUser, $ChoiceAddUserCSV)
    $SubUserMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleUser, $MessageUser, $SubUserOptions, 0)
}
```

This will cause the the other prompts to only be shown when the user selects the appropriate choice.

The next problem is that if you run this script in a loop, allowing for multiple sequential selections, the value of $SubGroupMenu and $SubUserMenu will not be overwritten. If on iteration 1 you choose choice 1 for the group menu then on iteration 2 the variable $SubGroupMenu will still hold the value of '1' and will trigger the subsequent switch case (unless that particular prompt is called again and a new choice made). In order to prevent this behavior you can do the following after your main menu prompt:

```
if($MainMenu -eq 1){
$SubGroupOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddGroup, $ChoiceAddGroupCSV)
    $SubGroupMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleGroup, $MessageGroup, $SubGroupOptions, 0)
}
else{
    $SubGroupMenu = $null
}
if($MainMenu -eq 2){
$SubUserOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddUser, $ChoiceAddUserCSV)
    $SubUserMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleUser, $MessageUser, $SubUserOptions, 0)
}
else{
    $SubUserMenu = $null
}
```

Note that this is the same as the snippet above where I added the condition, now I simply add the else statement setting the variable to $null. You cannot use an elseif here because you must make sure that both variables are overwritten.

If you want the entire script to be driven by the switches then you will have to do something like placing the sub menu prompts within the code block of the main menu switch like this:

```
$MainOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceOU, $ChoiceGroup, $ChoiceUser, $UserList, $DeleteUser, $EditUser)
    $MainMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $Message, $MainOptions, 0)

switch ($MainMenu)
    {
        0 {"You selected OU"}
        1 {$SubGroupOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddGroup, $ChoiceAddGroupCSV)
    $SubGroupMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleGroup, $MessageGroup, $SubGroupOptions, 0)}
        2 {$SubUserOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] ($ChoiceAddUser, $ChoiceAddUserCSV)
    $SubUserMenu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($TitleUser, $MessageUser, $SubUserOptions, 0)}
        3 {"You selected User List"}
        4 {"You selected Delete User"}
        5 {"You selected Edit User"}
    }
```

This solution will run into the same problem mentioned above about multiple iterations. So again you will have to make sure that the submenu variables are overwritten, and they cannot be set to the default 0, otherwise the 0 case will execute for them. This can be accomplished within the case code blocks for the main menu case by setting those variables to $null in addition to the text that is being written. Like this:

```
0 {"You selected OU"; $SubGroupMenu = $null; $SubUserMenu = $null}
```

Please note that while this solution certainly works, if the application becomes more complicated you may want to rethink your control logic rather than trying to force everything into those cases.